# "The type or namespace name could not be found" in ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm currently trying ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2. I've created it as a .NET Framework project (as opposed to a .NET Core project) and added references to our `Models` library, using .NET Framework 4.5, via a project reference:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net46": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Project.Core": {
        "target": "project"
      },
      "Project.DataAccess": {
        "target": "project"
      },
      "Project.Encryption": {
        "target": "project"
      },
      "Project.Models": {
        "target": "project"
      },
      "Project.Resources": {
        "target": "project"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Now when adding a model directive to my view, the following error occurs:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.User>

The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.User>>
The type or namespace name 'Project' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
        public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.User>> Html { get; private set; }
```

It also displays in intellisense: *Cannot resolve tag 'Project.Models.User'* and *Cannot resolve symbol 'model'*

I have added a project reference, added a using statement... Still this error occurs. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in RC2 [with an open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4686). A [workaround](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4686#issuecomment-220779628) in the issue discussion that works for me is:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorOptions(options =>
{
    var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
    options.CompilationCallback = context =>
    {
        previous?.Invoke(context);
        context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MyClass).Assembly.Location));
    };
    });
```

In your example, you'd need to do this for `Project.Models.User`.

Not sure whether [4.6.1 and Update 2 is needed for both projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37590355/7724), I've only tried with that.

Comment: This bug is still present in ASP.NET Core 1.1 under Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: From the comments on https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4686 and https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/755 it looks like people have successfully resolved this. What if you try the methods described there? @MichaelMortensen

Comment: I resolved it using your answer, and I filed a bug to Microsoft. I am running VS2017.

Answer (score 3):

The class library project has to have been created in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and it must use .NET Framework 4.6.1.  And your ASP.NET Core project must use .NET Framework 4.6.1 as well.

RC2 is the first version that supposedly supports including class libraries.  But I've found that if your class library has certain dependencies (like `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`) it will fail to load at runtime.

Comment: Is there a real difference when creating the library project (that was created by VS 2010 or so a few years back) when it uses .NET Framework 4.6.1?

Comment: Yes, a big difference.  This is something that the Microsoft devs are apparently struggling with.  I've confirmed that it only works when both projects have been created in VS 2015 Update 2 and both use 4.6.1.  Remember this is pre-release and things may change.  But for now, that's how it is.

Comment: Clint - I'm happy you chose to continue contributing.  I upvoted this answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as soon as I come home and vote accordingly. However: Where's the difference between the project files when created with different versions of VS? Because then I'd *only* need to modify the project files in order for it to work instead of re-creating the entire project. And about pre-release: Well, it might be pre-release, but it's licensed for "go-live" :p

Comment: I wouldn't even try to figure out all the details about the differences between VS Update 1 and Update 2.  ASP.NET Core and .NET Core is a generational leap.  This isn't like any of the .NET Framework updates in the past six years.  This is a whole new stack that is completely incompatible with earlier versions.  And RC2 isn't anywhere near go-live.  RC2 is more of a beta release because it's the first release to use the new .NET Core CLI.  That's one of the big differences between VS Update 1 and Update 2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wonder why Microsoft communicates this as a "production ready" release then... Makes me wonder if I *really* should start my new project with RC2.

Comment: I've been working on a new project using ASP.NET 5/Core for the last six months and have been able to figure out a work-around for all my issues.  Including this dll issue.  Instead of using a class library project, I create an ASP.NET Core web application project and delete everything except for project.json.  Then add all my shared code, models and middleware to that project.  I could go on and on about all the work-arounds I've had to figure out.  But the point is that it's possible if you're willing to make some short term sacrifices knowing things will have to be reworked later.

Comment: I've now come around to check this. I've changed the project to build on .NET FX 4.6.1 and the metadata of the project file looks exactly like one created with VS 2015 Update 2. However, the error still persists. (Note: It's still a class library, not a .NET Core class library)

Comment: Update: I also created a new ASP.NET Core Framework project and a new class library, still to no avail. Doesn't work. `The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    public class _Views_Home_About_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<IEnumerable<ClassLibrary1.Class1>>`

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by examining the file _ViewImports.cshtml.  That is where all usings go that get loaded in to all views.

For Instance -

```
@using MyProject
@using MyProject.Models
@using MyProject.Models.AccountViewModels
@using MyProject.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that the preserveCompilationContext is present and true in the project.json buildOptions has fixed this issue for me with Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "warningsAsErrors": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
    },
```